# how to make Links in web view clickable in android

Tags: android, webview, hyperlink, android-webview

i have a web view in which i am loading URL who has multiple links but when i click on any link its not working i check the URL in browser every thing is working but in web view its not working anyone please help me what is the problem here is my code

```
browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.racehistory_webView);
private void gotoPage(){

    browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new Callback()); 
    browser.loadUrl(url);

}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient{  

     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         view.loadUrl(url);
         return true;
     }


}
```

Comment: url mean some html page and added href tab in html that clickable

Comment: Please don't call loadUrl from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` as it is called for subframes with non-https schemes. If you go to a a page like http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet your code will end up calling view.loadUrl('tel:1234') and you will end up showing an error page, since the webview doesn't know how to load a tel: URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, are you sure that the HTML code is working on other browser? or that the code in HTML is properly supported from WebView? 
I've tried the code you posted and it seems work without error, are you sure that you use the internet permission?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: i didn't add the permission :)

Answer (score 0):

url is Some Html Page That Load in `Webview` 
in Html Page That Hane `href Tag` so that click and open New Html Page On any Link